# “reason of doing something”

Tags: grammaticality

I’ve recently stumbled upon a “key word transformation” sentence which sounded like this:

> The poor harvest led to many families leaving the island.

It had to be transformed using the word “reason”. I rewrote it as follows:

> The poor harvest was the reason of many families leaving the island.

Is that wrong? I can’t find any information about it on the internet.

Comment: How did you search the internet for this? What do you think, is it correct or not? Tell us why.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it's wrong.

We don't talk about **the reason of ** something.

Your options are:

> The poor harvest was the reason for many families leaving the island.

or, which I prefer:

> The poor harvest was the reason that many families left the island.